# ObjectiveC framework not export some classes

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks

I have developed a tool called EzoRed (ezored.com). It generate a framework for ios or aar for android with native code (c++).

When i get the generated xcode project and drag/drop into my sample project, i use the framework without problems. When i drag the generated framework only (With Debug version of framework everything is working fine, but with Release is not working.), my app compile, install on device or simulator but when i run i get error:

[image]

I use the **nm** tool to check exported symbols and see that only ***Impl** classes was exported. See:

> nm -gU build/ios/Release-universal/EzoRed.framework/EzoRed

```
0000000000010a88 S _OBJC_CLASS_$_EZRAudioStreamerPlatformServiceImpl
0000000000010b28 S _OBJC_CLASS_$_EZRGreetingMessagePlatformServiceImpl
00000000000109e8 S _OBJC_CLASS_$_EZRHttpClientPlatformServiceImpl
0000000000010ab0 S _OBJC_METACLASS_$_EZRAudioStreamerPlatformServiceImpl
0000000000010b50 S _OBJC_METACLASS_$_EZRGreetingMessagePlatformServiceImpl
0000000000010a10 S _OBJC_METACLASS_$_EZRHttpClientPlatformServiceImpl
0000000000010d30 D __ZTIPU39objcproto28EZRHttpClientPlatformService11objc_object
0000000000010fa0 D __ZTIPU42objcproto31EZRAudioStreamerPlatformService11objc_object
0000000000011200 D __ZTIPU44objcproto33EZRGreetingMessagePlatformService11objc_object
0000000000010d18 D __ZTIU39objcproto28EZRHttpClientPlatformService11objc_object
0000000000010f88 D __ZTIU42objcproto31EZRAudioStreamerPlatformService11objc_object
00000000000111e8 D __ZTIU44objcproto33EZRGreetingMessagePlatformService11objc_object
000000000000c700 S __ZTSPU39objcproto28EZRHttpClientPlatformService11objc_object
000000000000c9c0 S __ZTSPU42objcproto31EZRAudioStreamerPlatformService11objc_object
000000000000cca0 S __ZTSPU44objcproto33EZRGreetingMessagePlatformService11objc_object
000000000000c740 S __ZTSU39objcproto28EZRHttpClientPlatformService11objc_object
000000000000ca00 S __ZTSU42objcproto31EZRAudioStreamerPlatformService11objc_object
000000000000cce0 S __ZTSU44objcproto33EZRGreetingMessagePlatformService11objc_object
```

It is very strange because everything compile without problem.

With Debug version of framework everything is working fine. But with Release is not working.

Some checks:

It was included in bridge file:
https://github.com/ezored/sample-app/blob/master/source/ios/SampleApp/SampleApp/SampleApp-Bridging-Header.h

It was on CMakeLists.txt:
https://github.com/ezored/sample-app/blob/master/vendor/target-ios-master/CMakeLists.txt#L132

It compiles and install without problems, but not run. It show the up message.

All project files are here, anyone can download and run:
https://github.com/ezored/sample-app

The commands used are:

```
cmake --build . --config Debug  (is exported all files correct)
cmake --build . --config Release  (is exported only *Impl files)
```

The xcode direct command has the same effect:

```
xcodebuild build -configuration "Debug"  (is exported all files correct)
xcodebuild build -configuration "Release"  (is exported only *Impl files)
```

What im doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that i found is put on my CMakeLists.txt the line:

> CXX_VISIBILITY_PRESET default

Because on file **ios.cmake** i have the lines:

`set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${XCODE_IOS_PLATFORM_VERSION_FLAGS} ${BITCODE} -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-arc ${CXX_FLAGS}")`

https://github.com/ezored/target-ios/blob/master/build/files/ios.cmake#L284

I dont know if it is a best practice and i will try aprove the app on App Store with it.